# Error while returning mappings in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

How can I return a list of mapping for a specific data? My purpose is to be able to view all the created offers to the users specifically by searching.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
contract MyContract {

    uint public numberOfOffer;
    address[] public buyersAddresses; // stores the addresses of buyers


    struct offerModel {
        address sellerWalletAddress;
        string sellerName;
        uint itemCount;
        string itemName;
        string itemSpecification;
        uint itemPrice;

    }

    // we map a unique ID for each offer
    mapping (uint => offerModel) public offers;


    function createOffer(string _sellerName , uint _itemCount, string _itemName , string _itemSpecification , uint _itemPrice) external {

        numberOfOffer ++;
        offers[numberOfOffer].sellerWalletAddress = msg.sender;
        offers[numberOfOffer].sellerName = _sellerName;
        offers[numberOfOffer].itemCount = _itemCount;
        offers[numberOfOffer].itemName = _itemName;
        offers[numberOfOffer].itemSpecification = _itemSpecification;
        offers[numberOfOffer].itemPrice = _itemPrice;

    }

    function searchOffers (string _itemName) public view returns(string) {
        for(uint i=0;i<numberOfOffer;i++)
        {
            if(keccak256(offers[i].itemName) == keccak256(_itemName)){
                return offers[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
contract.sol:39:24: TypeError: Return argument type struct MyContract.offerModel storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory.
                return offers[i];

                       ^-------^
```

when I return `offers[i].itemName` I don't get the error

Comment: The function is defined as returning a string, not a struct (i.e. `returns(string)`)...

Answer (score 0):

The function should be returning the struct `offerModel` and not a string. Try this

```
    function searchOffers(string memory _itemName) external view returns (offerModel memory) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < numberOfOffer; i++) {
            if (keccak256(offers[i].itemName) == keccak256(_itemName)) {
                return offers[i];
            }
        }
    }

    function getAllOffers() external view returns (offerModel[] memory) {
        offerModel[] memory allOffers = new offerModel[](numberOfOffer);
        for (uint256 i; i < numberOfOffer; i++) allOffers[i] = offers[i];
        return allOffers;
    }
```

Comment: now I get something like this: 
```
contract.sol:35:66: TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.
    function searchOffers (string _itemName) public view returns(offerModel memory) {
                                                                 ^---
```

Comment: perhaps using a newer solidity compiler would help. You didn't specify a version in your contract.sol. There's no reason to be using old compilers, use 0.8.10